# Kirby CMS on NGINX server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, digital-ocean, kirby

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server on DigitalOcean configured with NGINX virtual host in which I'm attempting to host a Kirby CMS site on.

The front page works fine, but I get a 404 on any other page.

Kirby is installed to directories deep (*website.com/sub/dir/*)

Not sure if it's best to use a reverse proxy for Apache, or to fix up Kirby so it works with NGINX, or what the best way to do either of those is...

Does anyone have an answer to this? I'll provide whatever info you need to make this easier for you.

---

Here are some (hopefully) helpful files:

***etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.com***

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/website.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

***/etc/nginx/nginx.conf***

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    server {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;


proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Same problem here… Did you solve this already?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that MOD_REWRITE is supported and enabled. If this doesn't fix it, try with another web server such as Apache and LiteSpeed. I only tried with those two, so I can't talk to much about NGINX.
I assume that the .htaccess file has been copied to your server.